# Sharepoint - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'newColumns' of undefined

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

I am creating a list using Javascript. But while adding column to list it is getting error

```
function createlist() {
    // Create a generic SharePoint list with the name that the user specifies.
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    var listTitle = "MyList";
    listCreationInfo.set_title(listTitle);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
    lists = web.get_lists();
    var newList = lists.add(listCreationInfo);

    var newCols = [  "<Field Name='PageText' DisplayName='Page Text' Type='Note' RichText='TRUE'   RichTextMode='FullHtml' NumLines='10' />",
    true];

    var numberCols = newCols.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < numberCols; i++) {
            this.newColumns= newList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(newCols[i],true,SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
     }


    context.load(numberCols);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onListCreationSuccess, onListCreationFail);
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'newColumns' of undefined
>
> createlist @ App.js:57
>
> (anonymous function) @ App.js:18
>
> b.Callbacks.c @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
>
> b.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
>
> b.extend.ready @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3 H @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3

Help me where i am making mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example contains some *errors/typos*:

- `SP.FieldCollection.addFieldAsXml` function accepts field xml (`string type`) as first parameter but you are passing Boolean(!) value from `newCols` array

  `SP.ClientContext.load` function accepts `SP.ClientObject` object but at line: `context.load(numberCols);` `numberCols` is a *numeric value*

**Modified example**

Below is provided a slightly modified version of your example:

```
function createlist(listTitle,fieldDefs,success,error) {

    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title(listTitle);
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
    var list = web.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
    var fields = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldDefs.length; i++) {
         var field = list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(fieldDefs[i],true,SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
         fields.push(field);
         ctx.load(field);
    }
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            success(fields);
        }, error);
}
```

Usage

```
var listTitle = 'Requests';
var fieldDefs = [  "<Field Name='RequestDesc' DisplayName='Request Description' Type='Note' RichText='TRUE'   RichTextMode='FullHtml' NumLines='10' />"];

createlist(listTitle,fieldDefs,
  function(fields){
      console.log('List has been created successfully');
  },
  function(sender,args)
  {
      console.log(args.get_message()); 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test the code, but I see the following issues:

1) After adding your new list, you should load it:

```
var newList = lists.add(listCreationInfo);
context.load(newList);
```

2) Why you have true value in the array with the columns you would like to add? I suggest removing it. Or if you want to create one column, do as follows:

```
var newCol = "<Field Name='PageText' DisplayName='Page Text' Type='Note' RichText='TRUE'   RichTextMode='FullHtml' NumLines='10' />";
```

3) Instead of the loop, do this:

```
var newColumn = newList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(newCol,true,SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
```

4) Call load method on the new column and execute query:

```
context.load(newColumn);
context.executeQueryAsync(onListCreationSuccess, onListCreationFail);
```

You were calling `context.load(numberCols);` where `numberCols` was length of the array with columns to be created - the code due the error did not reach that line, but it would fail here as well.

I hope that helps.